# Store and Display Image in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, image, spring-boot, jsp, project-structure

I am trying to save a logo(in the project not in DB) and fetch it and display it on the JSP page For that I am saving the URL of the image in the DB but when I fetch it I am not getting the Image here is my code and screenshot of the project structure please help me here and please Let me know if this is the correct folder or I should save images somewhere else Thanks.

**File Save Method**

```
public static String storeLogoPath(MultipartFile file) {
        logger.info("File AAYA HAI " + file);
        String path = "";
        try {
            //String paths = "G:/MainWorkSpace/Picture_testing/WebContent/resources/images/"+file.getOriginalFilename();
            path = "G:/MainWorkSpace/TestProjects/ecomProject/src/main/resources/static/img/storeLogo/"+file.getOriginalFilename();
            File newFile = new File(path);
            newFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream myfile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            myfile.write(file.getBytes());
            myfile.close();
            logger.info("File should be saved now :: ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return path;
    }
```

**Controller Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/storeFormshow" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addStoreForm(Model theModel) {
        Stores storeObj = new Stores();
        theModel.addAttribute("storeForm",storeObj);
        return "Store/storeForm";
    }
```

**JSP PAGE FOR LIST**

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/Store/StoreTemplet/Header.jsp"%>


<div class="content-wrapper">
                <table class="table" id="table_id">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Logo</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Store Name</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Store Status</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <c:forEach var="store" items="${storeList}">
                            <tr>
                            <td> <img src="${store.logoURL}" width="10" height="10"> </td>
                                <td>${store.id}</td>
                                <td><a>${store.storeName}</a></td>
                                <td>${store.country}</td>
                                <td>${store.storeStatus}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</div>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/Store/StoreTemplet/Footer.jsp"%>
```

**Project Structure**
[image]

**The URL returned for the Images**
G:/MainWorkSpace/TestProjects/ecomProject/src/main/resources/static/img/storeLogo/Screenshot_2018-07-11-21-46-48.jpg"

**Application Properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp


spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String storeLogoPath(MultipartFile file) {
    logger.info("File AAYA HAI " + file);
    String path = "";
    try {
        path = "G:/MainWorkSpace/TestProjects/ecomProject/src/main/resources/static/img/storeLogo/"+file.getOriginalFilename();
        File newFile = new File(path);
        newFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream myfile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        myfile.write(file.getBytes());
        path ="/img/storeLogo/"+file.getOriginalFilename();
        myfile.close();
        logger.info("File should be saved now :: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("Path Returned is ::: "  + path);
    return path;
}
```

I have trimmed the path from the static folder and saved it in the DB

This is not the correct way of doing it but It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

add your images to resources/static folder and then access them like below in the img tags

```
<img src="/images/solr.png" height="50" width="50">
```

Comment: The reason I used the folder storelogo is I have to store a lot of images actually the functionality I wanted is that the user can add a logo and a profile picture both should be stored in different folders so the names should not duplicate and create confusion While I was using Spring MVC structure I used to save the images under web apps and the images are easy to access but In spring boot the images are not accessible easily and for the path the is returned by the Database so I cannot just simply pass the specific path of Image here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={`http://localhost:8080/api/employees/${employee.id}/image`} style={{'height':'50px','width':'50px'}}></img>
```

Use above code snippets to get image from server,
You can change url as per your machine